# Is there a way to access the macOS terminal environment variables from VS Code ipynb?

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, command-line-interface

I have credentials that are in my environment that I initialise through my CLI. However, I can't access these credentials from my python notebook in VS Code. When I check

```
os.environ
```

my credentials aren't there.

Is there a way to get these credentials on my python notebook?

Comment: Did you start VS Code from the shell in which the environment variables were exported?

Comment: Yep, I did ```code test.ipynb```

Comment: I tried it again, I think I get what you mean. I started VS Code from the shell with the folder containing my python notebook and it works!